# Why would a server not set a HTTP Response Code?

Tags: http, response

I'm asking in generalities - why would any server not set and return headers and/or status codes? I can't think of a good reason for this. Perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Comment: Sorry Thomas, I'm a grammar nazi :)

Comment: More details needed.  What client?  Server?  App framework?

Comment: Greg - It doesn't matter. Any server. What would cause someone to prevent the server from returning a status code or header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Status-Code is a required part of a HTTP Response.

By definition, the only reason for a server not to provide a Status-Line is that it is not a HTTP server.

[RFC 2616, section 6: Response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6).

Or said in a slightly less pedant way: if it does this, the server is hopelessly buggy and you should run away from it screaming.

Comment: Interesting...it appears that the PEAR HTTP classes do not proceed with an invalid security certificate...how they know that is beyond me, but I began checking the URLs that I'm looking at in a browser and so far, they all have an invalid certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Status codes were introduced in HTTP/1.0 - prior to this, [things were much simpler](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) - there were no headers in the request or the response.

A request was simply like this, with no indication of the protocol version

```
GET /
```

The response would be all body, with no headers.

So it looks like you are talking to some kind of antique webserver which only speaks HTTP/0.9!

Comment: HTTP/0.9 ... that must be last millennium :-)